# An equality involving random vectors

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $X_i$, for $i\in\{1,\cdots,n \}$, be independent and identically distributed random variables. Let $X_i\in S=\{e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n \}$ where $e_i$ are standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&\cdots 0\\
0&0&1&\cdots 0\\
\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots 1 \\
1&1&1&\cdots1
 \end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}$$

> I am wanting to know if $$P(\sum_{i=1}^n A^iX_i = m+A^jx) = \sum_{y\in S} P(X_j=y,\sum_{i\neq j} A^iX_i = m+A^j(x-y))\tag{1}$$ is true? Here $P(\cdot)$ is the probability of an event, $m,x$ are $n-$dim vectors whose entries are in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and matrix multiplication and addition is done in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

If $A,e_1,\cdots,e_n$ were integers as opposed to $A$ being a matrix, $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ being vectors  and if all the arithmetic were done in $\mathbb{Z}$, then I know that $(1)$ is true.

I would think even if we have $A$ as a matrix, $e_i$ as vectors and if the arithmetic is over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $(1)$ is true because all we are saying is that:

\begin{align}
P\left(\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n A^iX_i = m+A^jx\right\}\right)&=P\left(\bigcup_{y\in S} \left\{X_j=y,\sum_{i\neq j} A^iX_i = m+A^j(x-y)) \right\}\right)\\
&= \sum_{y\in S} P(X_j=y,\sum_{i\neq j} A^iX_i = m+A^j(x-y))
\end{align}

because the union above is a disjoint union. Am I correct here?

Comment: It all looks good at quick glance. I'm curious, iss the fact that the aritmetic is over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ even necessary?

Comment: @AnderAguirre Good question, probably not. But if $\sum_{i=1}^n A^iX_i = Y_n$, then I am looking at $Y_n$ as a random walk on vertices of a hypercube and so was doing arithmetic over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.